# GoDaddy Perl modules

Tags: godaddy

Is there any way to find out the list of Perl modules provided by GoDaddy hosting without actually getting a hosting account?

Comment: Have you tried asking their support?

Answer (score 2):

No. [Their process](http://community.godaddy.com/help/1488/can-i-add-perl-modules-to-my-hosting-account) involves going through your account. They have several data centers, so it's conceivable their systems aren't always in sync. This would ensure that whatever information they show you actually applies to you. If you absolutely need to know before signing up, then John's suggestion is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to godaddy hosting connection, the place from where you'll install those modules after you buy the hosting. you can still browse or if you cant then just make a free account and dont buy anything. then you'll be able to check whats there and whats not there...